# reshaping daily data on intraday values pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF that looks like this:

```
                             Last
1996-02-26 09:31:00     65.750000
1996-02-26 09:32:00     65.890625
1996-02-26 09:33:00           NaN

1996-03-27 09:31:00    266.710000
1996-03-27 09:32:00    266.760000
1996-03-27 09:33:00    266.780000
```

I want to reshape my data to look like such:

```
         1996-02-26    1996-03-27
9:31:00   65.75           266.71
9:32:00   65.890625       266.76
9:33:00   NaN             266.78
```

How can I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your index is `str` dtype, create a MultiIndex and call `unstack`:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(zip(*df.index.str.split()))
df = df.set_index(idx)['Last'].unstack(0)

print(df)
          1996-02-26  1996-03-27
09:31:00   65.750000      266.71
09:32:00   65.890625      266.76
09:33:00         NaN      266.78
```

---

An alternative solution if the index values are `datetimes`:

```
idx =  pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index.time, df.index.floor('D')])
df = df.set_index(idx)['Last'].unstack()

print(df)
          1996-02-26  1996-03-27
09:31:00   65.750000      266.71
09:32:00   65.890625      266.76
09:33:00         NaN      266.78
```

Comment: Seems like .str is complaining about some of my values.. `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values (i.e. inferred_type is 'string', 'unicode' or 'mixed')` but I don't think any of my dates are incorrect or bad values. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Pandas `pivot_table`, assuming that your dataframe has a single level `datetime` index. Assign `date` and `time` to separate variables and then use this approach

```
date = df.index.date
time = df.index.time
# Use pivot_table to reshape dataframe
df_reshaped = df.pivot_table(index=time, columns=date, values='Last')
df_reshaped

          1996-02-26  1996-03-27
09:31:00   65.750000      266.71
09:32:00   65.890625      266.76
09:33:00         NaN      266.78
```

Comment: This assumes the index is already a MultiIndex... which (according to OP) is actually a single index of datetime objects.

Comment: Thank you. Will alter my answer.

Comment: Hope it proved to be useful. Cheers!